# Can I customize lombok to writing code for each variable in class similar to getters and setters?

Tags: java, lombok

I have same set of code that I should write for each variable that I declare in class similar to getters and setters. Can I customize lombok to do this, or is there any other way to do this?

```
public class Test {
    
    String t1;
    String t2;
```

These are the repetitive methods that I write for every variable that I declare.

```
public String TestT1() {
   test(t1);
   return t1;
}

public String TestT2() {
    test(t2);
    return t2;
}

private void test(String t1) {
    System.out.println("For Example");
}
```

}

Comment: Configure your IDE to generate the text from a template.

Comment: But my class should cleaner , something like Lombok..

Comment: Consider parameterized testing.  IIRC this is in junit5.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Custom Templates in Eclipse IDE. Not exact same but it will help.

- Go to **Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Templates**.
- Click on **New** button add template code as given in screenshot.

  public String Test${arg:localVar}() {
  test(${arg:localVar});
  return ${arg:localVar};
  }

[image]

- In Java Editor, press **Ctrl + Space** and type your method name. (In my case it will be **TestMethods** as given while creating New Template) (Refer below screenshot)

[image]

- Press Enter, eclipse will automatically add code template as created. Type your variable name just after pressing enter. (Refer next two screenshots)

[image]

- After typing variable name.

[image]